# Deserializar JSON to Object en Java

Tags: java, string, object

¿Cómo puedo deserializar el atributo `properties` del `Object -> templateComponents` para poder acceder solo a la información de `latitude, longitude y name`?


Ahora mismo `properties` es un `String` y necesito que sea un `Object`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es algo raro como has hecho la pregunta, no se acaba de entender lo de pasarlo a un objeto, ¿para qué?¿No será a un objeto JSON? Mira esta página, creo que te resolverá las dudas: http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplos_JSON_y_Java_con_Gson

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano es deserializar en 'properties' que es un JSON a un Object.
Gracias, voy a mirar eso.

Comment: Tienes que decir si ya estás trabajando con un objeto JSON o no, si usas alguna librería o no para poder decirte la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Ese properties lo podés convertir a un objecto Java usando la librería `Gson`.

Necesitas una clase que modele ese objeto y luego `Gson` se encarga de la deserialización.

Lamentablemente pegaste una imagen en lugar de poner texto así que el ejemplo contempla solo los tres primeros atributos.

```
public class MisPropiedades{
    @SerialName("latitude")
    private double latitud;
    @SerialName("longitude")
    private double longitud;
    @SerialName("name")
    private String nombre;
    ...

    // Aca getters y setters
}
```

Luego en el programa:

```
...
String props = templateComponenets.get(4).getProperties(); // Supongo que esto devuelve el string properties
MisPropiedades misPropiedades = new Gson().fromJson(props, MisPropiedades.class);
...
```

Y en `misPropiedades` tenes instanciado el objeto.

[Acá podes conseguir la librería ya sea el jar o como incluirlo en maven.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5)